# Android-RecyclerView how to prepare items in recyclerview before they become visible?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have videos in my recyclerview and i want them to load before they become visible.So user dont wait it to load and play with no delay like instagram.

Is there any method for that?

for example:

```
recyclerView.loadItemsBeforeTheyBecomeVisible(int numberOfLoadingItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an asynctask to load the videos, once the asynctask finish execute your method to setup the recyclerview
Something like this

YourActivityClass

```
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ..........
       YourASynctask yourasynctask = new YourASynctask (pass params if it's necessary);
       yourasynctask.execute();
}
```

In your Asynctask

```
public class YourAsynctaskextends AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<ListaLineal>> {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public YourAsynctask() {

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
//show progressdialog
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity,"Cargando","Espere por favor...",false,false);

}

@Override
protected < doInBackground(Void... voids) {

   //load video here and return whatever you need to

    return something;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute() {
    super.onPostExecute();
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    YourActivityClass.setupData();
}
```

And Finally for this you need to have a void in your ActivityClass to setup rv like

```
public void setupData(){
            yourRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerid);
            yourRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            rvAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    yourRV.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
}
```